# Finding the eigenvalue of a block matrix given below

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given a block matrix $F$ and $V$ defined below
$$F = \begin{bmatrix} F_{11} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} , \textrm{ and } V = \begin{bmatrix} V_{11} & 0 \\ V_{21} & V_{22} \end{bmatrix},$$
so that
$$V^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} V_{11}^{-1} & 0 \\- V_{22}^{-1}V_{21}V_{11}^{-1} & V_{22}^{-1} \end{bmatrix}. $$
Now, I am going to find for the eigenvalue $(\lambda)$ of the matrix $FV^{-1}$, so we have

\begin{align}
det(FV^{-1} -  \lambda I) &= det \left( \begin{bmatrix}  F_{11} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} V_{11}^{-1} & 0 \\- V_{22}^{-1}V_{21}V_{11}^{-1} & V_{22}^{-1} \end{bmatrix} - \lambda I\right)= 0 \\   \Rightarrow  & \ det \left( F_{11} V_{11}^{-1} - \lambda I \right) det(-\lambda I) = 0 \\ \Rightarrow  & \ det \left( F_{11} V_{11}^{-1} - \lambda I \right)  = 0.
\end{align}
Is there a way that I can get the eigenvalue ($\lambda$) without solving the determinant, i.e., in a way that I can express the eigenvalue ($\lambda$) in terms of the other matrix?

Comment: There is no way to compute this eigenvalue in closed for or by hand that takes advantage of the fact that it's written in the form $F_{11}V_{11}^{-1}$. However, you might find it interesting the the eigenvalues of $FV^{-1}$ are the [generalized eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem) of the pair $(F,V)$. Similarly, the roots of $\det(F_{11} V_{11}^{-1})$ are the generalized eigenvalues of the pair $(F_{11},V_{11})$.